# 'Array#select' in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two arrays of hashes:

```
data = [
  {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "Rob",
    "age": "22",
    "job": "Tester"
  },
  {
    "id": 101,
    "name": "Matt",
    "age": "28",
    "job": "Engineer"
  }
]

compare_data = [{"age": "21"},{"age": "29"},{"age": "22"}]
```

`compare_data` has `{age: 22}`, which matches one of the hashes inside `data array`. I'm trying to get an array of `data` elements that match `compare_data`. I expect to get:

```
[{:id=>100, :name=>"Rob", :age=>"22", :job=>"Tester"}]
```

The following is the code:

```
data.select do |each_item| 
  compare_data.map do |child| 
    child[:age].include?(each_item[:age])
  end
end
new_array # => {:id=>100, :name=>"Rob", :age=>"22", :job=>"Tester"}{:id=>101, :name=>"Matt", :age=>"28", :job=>"Engineer"}
```

However, the return array has all values from `data`.

Comment: I don't understand clearly what is your desired out put? Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map all ages into an array and then select from the original array using the generated age array.

```
compare_data_age = compare_data.map { |x| x[:age] }.uniq

data.select { |x| compare_data_age.include? x[:age] }

=> [{:id=>100, :name=>"Rob", :age=>"22", :job=>"Tester"}]
```

Comment: thank you but if you look at my example inside map should fetch `age` value and so does each_item[:age]. Why that doesn't work ?

Comment: I am confused, so this is not the output you are expecting? Or are you asking me as to why your code does not work?

Comment: later, thats the result I was expecting. Thank you. But in my code I tried to combine map and select. So I was little confused where it failed.

Comment: The reason your code does not work is because the `map` block inside `select` block will return an array. Now `select` expects you to provide a boolean value for it to decide whether to select that entry or not. Since your inner block always returns an array which is treated as `true`, the select block will select all the data entries.

Comment: If you are still confused try doing
`data.select do |x|
   [false]
end` which will return the whole data array, where as replacing `[false]` with `false` will return nothing as expected.

Comment: thanks, I needed to understand where I made mistake. Thanks